# JNI Threads creation

Tags: java, multithreading, native

How can I create a Thread in JNI?

There is any Java environment function call? Or should I use c++ threads?

I believe I should use pthread as a normal c++ Application, but these create threads will call some java callback, maybe in syncronized methods.

Comment: Thread creation in windows and in linux is slightly different.In which environment you are working?

Comment: Both! I'm using pthread as thread library for c code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about native threads and JNI. Still there are a lot of things that can go wrong.

A native thread must be `attached` to the JVM before you can call any Java methods. The API functions that are important for this are:

```
jint AttachCurrentThread(JavaVM *vm, void **p_env, void *thr_args);
jint DetachCurrentThread(JavaVM *vm);
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) for more infos.

All the other stuff like `synchronized` is handled by the JVM.